# Eclipse connect Gitlab-Repo issue

Tags: eclipse, task, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04

First of all: I have had a working environment in Eclipse-IDE.

One day (without any changes but updates) in the eclipse-IDE I was not able to:

- handle my gitlab repo (fetch, pull, push, ...)
- sync my gitlab-tasks

When I will handle my gitlab repo I get the error: **cannot open git-upload-pack**.
And when I will sync my Task-List I get the error: **no route to host**

But I am still able to handle my gitlab-repo per cli without any problems.

I already have:

- reinstalled eclipse
- reinstalled java-jre
- restarted network services
- checked my proxy and firewall config (all empty)
- set up a new clean workspace in eclipse without any configuration but new gitlab-task connector setup -> same issue **no route to host**
- successful accessed my remote repo url with **nc hostname port**
- executed `sudo update-ca-certificates -f`

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- default-jre installed
- eclipse oxygen 1A with
  -- default git-connector and the gitlab-task-connector from http://pweingardt.github.com/mylyn-gitlab
- I access my remote per HTTP

Are there any more ideas what I can check or test to solve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo apt-get update ca-certificates-java` & `sudo update-ca-certificates -f` https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/853

Comment: the first command does not accept an argument -> tried with "upgrade" but there is none / the second command runned through but didnt changed anything